# Using the Intel WIDI or Intel wireless display on the Toshiba X875-q7390

Tags: windows-8, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

We are using a Toshiba Qosmio x875-q7390. We are attempting to use the Intel wireless display option on it. According to Intel and the Toshiba website it needs to use the Intel HD Graphics card. The system is using windows 8 with UEFI.

I have already attempted to disable the NVIDIA graphics card on the system or even enable the Intel HD graphics card but with no luck. 
We need help enabling the Intel HD graphics or disabling the NVIDIA graphics card.